# 429 - ActiveX component can't create object: What object?

Tags: debugging, com, activex

Context: trying to reduce the installation of an application to the absolute minimum number of files.  We are running the app and adding needed dependencies one by one.

But now we get a pop-up telling us that "429 - ActiveX component can't create object".  We know what it means, but we don't know what 'object' the application is trying to create at this time.

Is there a way to easily find out what object my application wants to instantiate?

Comment: Clearly you'll need a debugger or better exception handling to show you the exact line of code that produces this error.  You then know the "object" as well.  Backup plan is to use SysInternals' ProcMon and see the process searching for registry keys or files that are missing.

Comment: Try to monitor registry access to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and all keys under that and see which keys belong to your application. Unsuccessful lookups should point to the classes that are either not registered or registered but the .dll/.exe implementing them is missing.